# Yii2 Url i8n with sub-folder

Tags: yii2

I'm working on project with `i8n`, i have this `/config/web` (Yii2 Basic):

```
'article/<id:\d+>/<slug>' => 'article/view',
'<language:\w{2}>' => 'site/index',
'<language:\w{2}>/<_c:\w+>' => '<_c>',
'<language:\w{2}>/<_c:\w+>/<_a:\w+>' => '<_c>/<_a>',
'<language:\w{2}>/<_m:\w+>' => '<_m>',
'<language:\w{2}>/<_m:\w+>/<_c:\w+>' => '<_m>/<_c>',
'<language:\w{2}>/<_m:\w+>/<_c:\w+>/<_a:\w+>' =>
```

if i have this url:
`2012/it/site/index` - Work fine

but
`2012/it/folder/site/index` - not work (Error 404)

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

**First thing:**

There are some issues with these rules.

```
'<language:\w{2}>/<_c:\w+>' => '<_c>',
'<language:\w{2}>/<_m:\w+>' => '<_m>',
```

and

```
'<language:\w{2}>/<_c:\w+>/<_a:\w+>' => '<_c>/<_a>',
'<language:\w{2}>/<_m:\w+>/<_c:\w+>' => '<_m>/<_c>',
```

For application these two rules are treated the same so there is no point of adding all - just one of each. You need to find other way to set actions parameters.

**Second thing:**

Always set rules in order from most complex to less complex so it can be properly caught.

```
'article/<id:\d+>/<slug>' => 'article/view',
'<language:\w{2}>/<_c:\w+>/<_a:\w+>' => '<_c>/<_a>',
'<language:\w{2}>/<_c:\w+>' => '<_c>',
'<language:\w{2}>' => 'site/index',
```